# No return evaluation in nested if

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean-expression

After watching carefully the following code I can't see why the compiler is warning me with "warning: control reaches end of non-void function".

```
bool Foam::solidMagnetostaticModel::read()
{
    if (regIOobject::read())
    {
        if (permeabilityModelPtr_->read(subDict("permeability")) && magnetizationModelPtr_->read(subDict("magnetization")))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't see where is the problem, the else statement should care for returning false in every case which the first if is not true.

Comment: Is that a (even potentially) open source project or something proprietary?

Comment: This a library that I'm programming in the open source CFD platform OpenFOAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trace the code path when `regIOobject::read()` is true, but either of `permeabilityModelPtr_->read(subDict("permeability"))` or `magnetizationModelPtr_->read(subDict("magnetization"))` is false. In that case, you enter the top `if` block (excluding the possibility of entering its attached `else` block), but then fail to enter the nested `if` block:

```
bool Foam::solidMagnetostaticModel::read()
{
    if (regIOobject::read())
    {
        // Cool, read() was true, now check next if...
        if (permeabilityModelPtr_->read(subDict("permeability")) && magnetizationModelPtr_->read(subDict("magnetization")))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Oh no, it was false, now we're here...
    }
    else
    {
        // First if was true, so we don't go here...
        return false;
    }
    // End of function reached, where is the return???
}
```

The minimalist fix is to just remove the `else { }` wrapping, so any fallthrough ends up at `return false;`:

```
bool Foam::solidMagnetostaticModel::read()
{
    if (regIOobject::read())
    {
        // Cool, read() was true, now check next if...
        if (permeabilityModelPtr_->read(subDict("permeability")) && magnetizationModelPtr_->read(subDict("magnetization")))
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Oh no, it was false, now we're here...
    }
    // Oh, but we hit return false; so we're fine
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, avoid specifically mentioning `true` or `false` at all, since your function is logically just a result of `and`ing three conditions together:

```
bool Foam::solidMagnetostaticModel::read()
{
    // No need to use ifs or explicit references to true/false at all
    return regIOobject::read() &&
           permeabilityModelPtr_->read(subDict("permeability")) &&
           magnetizationModelPtr_->read(subDict("magnetization"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested if is the problem.

When that branch is not taken, there is no other paths to take

Answer (score 1):

> the else statement should care for returning false in every case which the first if is not true.

Correct, but what if the first `if` condition is true, but the second `if` condition is not?

That is: What if `regIOobject::read()` returns `true`, but `permeabilityModelPtr_->read(subDict("permeability"))` returns `false`?

Then the flow of control enters the first `if` block, does not return, but does not enter the `else` block (because the first condition was true), so it just falls off the end of the function without hitting a `return` statement.

If you want the `else { return false; }` part to apply to either condition, you could just naively copy/paste it:

```
if (COND1) {
    if (COND2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

But that's quite a bit of code duplication. A better solution is to replace the nested `if` by a single condition:

```
if (COND1 && COND2) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

There's still some duplication: Both branches consist of a `return` statement followed by some expression.

We can factor out the common parts (`return`) and push the condition into the expression:

```
return COND1 && COND2 ? true : false;
```

But `? true : false` is redundant: If the condition is true, evaluate to true, else evaluate to false? Well, that's just what the condition itself does:

```
return COND1 && COND2;
```

Or with your concrete expressions:

```
return regIOobject::read()
    && permeabilityModelPtr_->read(subDict("permeability"))
    && magnetizationModelPtr_->read(subDict("magnetization"));
```

Comment: Thanks @melpomene! this is an excellent explanation. I could not see it after looking at it several times (I know...). After trying to compile it without modification I could verify that the compiler was not wrong...:P. ; so as always, the problem was between the keyboard and the monitor. Thanks again!